# @SqlResultSetMapping in jpa Invalid column name error

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using a JOIN statement to get data from two tables(APPLICANT and ADDRESS) using a createNativeQuery.
 But I am getting a invalid column name error.
 The actual scenario is :

In Applicant class

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="menu-details",
        entities={
                 @EntityResult(entityClass=Applicant.class, fields = {
                        @FieldResult(name="id", column="APPLICANT_ID"),
                        @FieldResult(name="contactNo", column="CONTACT_NO"),
                        @FieldResult(name="dateOfBirth", column="DATE_OF_BIRTH"),
                        @FieldResult(name="name", column="APPLICANT_NAME"),
                        @FieldResult(name="status", column="STATUS")
                      }),
           @EntityResult(entityClass=AddressA.class, fields = {
                    @FieldResult(name="state", column="STATE")
            })
    }
```

)

```
In DAO, I am trying
String nativeQuery="select distinct (LA. APPLICANT_ID) as APPLICANT_ID, LA.CONTACT_NO       as CONTACT_NO,LA.DATE_OF_BIRTH as DATE_OF_BIRTH,LA.APPLICANT_NAME as APPLICANT_NAME,  
LA.STATUS as STATUS, LAA.STATE as STATE from loan_applicant LA,   
loan_address_a LAA where LA.applicant_id=LAA.applicant_id";  
Query q=entityManager.createNativeQuery (nativeQuery,"menu-details");
ArrayList<Applicant> menuList=new ArrayList<Applicant>();
List<Object> objects=q.getResultList();
System.out.println("the no of queries is "+objects.size());
    for(Object object:objects){
        if(object instanceof Applicant){
            Applicant applicant=(Applicant)object;
            System.out.println(applicant.getId());
            System.out.println(applicant.getName());
            System.out.println(applicant.getContactNo());
        }
        if(object instanceof  AddressA){
            AddressA address=(AddressA)object;
            System.out.println(address.getState());
        }
    }




while executing I am getting an error
```

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccessdbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:269)`

Comment: You are specifying a SqlResultSetMapping be used, which tries to create Applicant and Address entities from the SQL results, but it seems incomplete.  For instance, does Address really only have a single State field?  If not, then the other fields required to build an Address need to also be returned.  Try using a select * in your native query as aliasing and FieldResult should not be necessary unless you are returning different fields from what you have mapped in the entity.

Answer (score 0):

you write :

```
from loan_applicant LA, loan_address_a LAA where La.applicant_id=la. applicant_id
```

maybe what you want is :

```
from loan_applicant LA, loan_address_a LAA where LA.applicant_id=LAA.applicant_id
```

Comment: :sorry that was a copy paste error.I have corrected the query here. In SQL Developer I am getting two records for the same query. I guess I am getting an error because of incorrect ordering of columns?

Comment: did the error happen when you do `q.getResultList()`? did that distinct realy needed? distinct + other variable will override the distinct. and remove the alias (as . . .) of all result column.